# How to print each of my output into a file

Tags: python

I am not quite sure how to print my output into a file.

Sample input

```
0
2
1
3
5
```

Content of dragon.dat for sample input

```
S
SLSLSRS
SLS
SLSLSRSLSLSRSRS
SLSLSRSLSLSRSRSLSLSLSRSRSLSRSRSLSLSLSRSLSLSRSRSRSLSLSRSRSLSRSRS
```

Here is my code:

```
infile = open("dragon.dat", "w")
def B(n):
    if n>22:
        return "Enter integer less than 22"

    elif n==0:
        return "S"
    str=B(n-1)
    reversestr=str
    str +="L"
    reversestr=reversestr.replace("L","T")
    reversestr=reversestr.replace("R","L").replace("T","R")
    reversestr=reversestr[::-1]
    return str + reversestr

print(B(0))    # these input will be printed in the python shell
print(B(2))
print(B(1))
print(B(3))
print(B(5))

infile.write(B(0))
infile.write(B(2))
infile.write(B(1))
infile.write(B(3))
infile.write(B(5))


infile.close()
```

my ouput in the file:

```
SSLSLSRSSLSSLSLSRSLSLSRSRSSLSLSRSLSLSRSRSLSLSLSRSRSLSRSRSLSLSLSRSLSLSRSRSRSLSLSRSRSLSRSRS
```

How am I able to separate them into each lines just like the sample output?

Comment: Use `'\n'` : `infile.write(B(0) + '\n')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `\n` while writing. Use `infile.write(B(i) + '\n')` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
infile.write("\n".join([B(i) for i in range(6)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use print: `print(B(1), file=infile)` or

```
print(*[B(i) for i in [0,2,1,3,5]], file=infile, sep='\n')
```